# Wordpress - need different number of posts on page 1 versus page 2 of category

Tags: php, wordpress

In a category section, I'm trying to display 5 posts on the first page and then the default number of posts (set to 6) on the 2nd and subsequent pages.

I've tried using `query_posts(posts_per_page=5)` on the first page but then the 2nd page displays posts 7 to 12 instead of posts 6 to 11 which is what I need. There is no continuity in the posts during the pagination between page 1 and page 2 when using `posts_per_page`.

I've come across a lot of articles on the web that seem to relate to this problem but can't find any solutions that work. Please, help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to achieve this by creating a custom archive page.
You could check:

```
get_query_var('paged');
```

Then, if the page is 1 use:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=5');
```

else use:

```
query_posts('paged='.(get_query_var('paged')-1).'&offset=5');
```

This will cause the effects that when viewing the archive i.e. the posts after the first 5, the first 5 posts will be completely ignored so page 1 of the archive will start at post 6.

Comment: You could also achieve this with a template tag such as `is_home()` or something to that regard.

Comment: hey mike, thanks for your answer. i'll give that a try and let you know.